# Breaking my neck with ProgressDialog and dismiss method issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've made a recipe app, i've been fixing a few issues because i couldn't get the app running but it seems that everytime a fix an error another one shows up, my project can't resolve method dismiss() i don't know what to do, i've made this app accordingly to an Youtube channel but it's giving me lots of issues, i don't know if i missed some code or if it's something else, i've also noticed that there are many things in my Dialog.java that cannot be resolved, such as setDefaultIcon, WindowDecorActionBar, @UnsupportedAppUsage, isDestroyed, setShowHideAnimationEnabled, IdRes among lots of other things, i don't even know where all of that comes from i'm a bit lost here.

This is my Upload_Recipe activity:

```
package com.example.recipeapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Upload_Recipe extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView recipeImage;
    Uri uri;
    EditText txt_name, txt_description, txt_price;
    String imageUrl;
    Object progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload__recipe);

        recipeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_foodImage);
        txt_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_recipe_name);
        txt_description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_description);
        txt_price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_price);


    }

    public void btnSelectImage(View view) {

        Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPicker.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPicker, 1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            uri = data.getData();
            recipeImage.setImageURI(uri);

        } else Toast.makeText(this, "Você não selecionou uma imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void uploadImage() {

        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("RecipeImage")
                .child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isComplete()) ;
                Uri urlImage = uriTask.getResult();
                if (urlImage != null) {
                    imageUrl = urlImage.toString();
                }
                uploadRecipe();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    public void btnUploadRecipe(View view) {

        uploadImage();

    }

    public void uploadRecipe() {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Enviando Receita...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        finish();

        FoodData foodData = new FoodData(txt_name.getText().toString()
                , txt_description.getText().toString(), txt_price.getText().toString()
                , imageUrl);

        String myCurrentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Recipe")
                .child(myCurrentDateTime).setValue(foodData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Toast.makeText(Upload_Recipe.this, "Receita Enviada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Upload_Recipe.this, "Falha ao Enviar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ProgressDialog(Object progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        ProgressDialog(progressDialog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write `progressDialog.dismiss();` this line into **uploadRecipe** method.

```
uploadRecipe();            
progressDialog.dismiss(); //Remove this line
```

Comment: Thanks now my app is finally running like it was supposed to cheers.